# What options are out there for quick-fix type functionality in emacs?

Tags: flycheck, flymake

When using `flycheck` or `flymake`, it would be nice to have quick fix functionality which gives suggested fixes and automatically applies them when selected like most IDE's provide.

So far the only thing i've found that seems to do this is:

https://github.com/ulises/quickfix-mode

But it looks like it isn't commonly used or actively maintained and only supports a couple of languages.

Is there anything else out there? or is there something built-in to some commonly used programming modes that I might be missing?

Comment: Discussion thread about standardizing an interface for fixers for flycheck might interest you: https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/issues/530

Answer (score 0):

There's a package called [attrap](https://github.com/jyp/attrap) that implements this complementary "fixer" behavior for flycheck (via the `attrap-attrap` function).  It's fairly straightforward to implement fixers for a new language/mode (see `attrap-flycheck-checkers-alist` and `attrap-elisp-fixer` as an example fixer function).